# What does arm crc32w do?

Tags: assembly, arm, crc, arm64

Seems like a dumb question, but the value it returns is not what I'm expecting...   I need to emulate the crc32w instrcution on an arm7 chip (which doesn't support this instruction), so I need a c implementation that gets the same result.  Everything I've tried differs.   According to the documentation at http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_asm/armclang_asm_awi1476352818103.htm, it should do:

> CRC32 takes an input CRC value in the first source operand, performs a
>   CRC on the input value in the second source operand, and returns the
>   output CRC value. The second source operand can be 8, 16, or 32 bits.
>   To align with common usage, the bit order of the values is reversed as
>   part of the operation, and the polynomial 0x04C11DB7 is used for the
>   CRC calculation

That's nice, but if I run:

```
uint32_t crc=0xFFFFFFFF; 
uint32_t val=100;
asm volatile("crc32w %w0, %w0, %w1": "+r" (crc): "r" (val)  );
```

Then I get a crc of `6aff40b7`.   If I plug the same numbers into http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html (or other online crc web pages) I get `0x6B9B7A5D`.   I tried toggling the reverse bits, etc, but I can't come up with `6aff40b7`.   So, my question is what exactly `crc32w` do?

Comment: On the mentioned javascript web page, when I select CRC-32, predefined CRC32_JAMCRC, bytes input `0x64 0x00 0x00 0x00` (32 bit value `100` in little endian encoding), I get result `0x6AFF40B7`. = but I have no idea what that means and how the particular CRC works, or what is JAMCRC, nor I'm planning to study it now. Just mentioning how to reach your desired value.

Comment: Ahh, I was looking at predefined CRC32...   Thanks.  That gives me something to look into (it looks like JAMCRC simply doesn't do the xor at the end...   I'll have to look into the endianess as well, as I'm running on a BE system...)

Comment: You should use separate `asm` operands for all 3 registers, like `"=r" (crc) : "r"(crc), "r"(val)` so the compiler can copy-and-crc if it wants.  Without an early-clobber (`&`), this doesn't *stop* the compiler from using the same register for input and output of the C variable `crc`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the HAL (Hardware Abstraction layer) with ARM CRC32
with the following set:

```
/* CRC init function */
void MX_CRC_Init(void)
{
  hcrc.Instance = CRC;
  hcrc.Init.DefaultPolynomialUse =  DEFAULT_POLYNOMIAL_ENABLE;
  hcrc.Init.DefaultInitValueUse = DEFAULT_INIT_VALUE_ENABLE;
  hcrc.Init.InputDataInversionMode =  CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_BYTE; // CRC_INPUTDATA_INVERSION_NONE;
  hcrc.Init.OutputDataInversionMode =  CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_ENABLE;  // CRC_OUTPUTDATA_INVERSION_DISABLE;
  hcrc.InputDataFormat = CRC_INPUTDATA_FORMAT_BYTES;
  if (HAL_CRC_Init(&hcrc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

I am getting results that agree with the CRC32/JAMCRC variant.
i.e. calling

```
  const char * ts3 = "123456789";
  MX_CRC_Init();
  crc32 =   HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, (uint32_t *)ts3, strlen(ts3));
```

gives 0x340bc6d9 in crc32 which corresponds to CRC-32/CRCJAM.
The bitwise NOT of it is the standard CRC-32.
I have no Idea why it is called JAM

```
  const char * ts2 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy brown dog";
  MX_CRC_Init();
  crc32 =   HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, (uint32_t *)ts2, strlen(ts2));
```

gave 0x38dd18f ~= 0xFC722E70

which both agree with https://crccalc.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
// This code assumes that unsigned is at least 4 bytes. If not, use
// unsigned long instead.

// When called with data == NULL, the initial CRC value is returned.
unsigned crc32jamcrc(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffffffff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: Good point, I still use xc8 and PIC18 where the default int is 16 bits and the long is 32.

Comment: another valid thing to note with STM-32 HAL s/w is : what STM call DATA_INVERSION really means bit-reversal or reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CRC32 engine in the stm32 feeding it whole little endian 32 bit words, then this C code will give you the same results as dropping uint32_t's on the CRC->DR.

```
// This is C code that gives the same results
// as sending words to the STM32 CRC engine.
// Most online calculators apply CRC's to bit reversed
// streams and will therefore, not give the same results.
// Optimally this would be done via DMA in the background.
//
uint32_t stm32_crc32(uint32_t crc, uint32_t data) {

    int i;
    crc = crc ^ data;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (crc & 0x80000000)
            crc = ((crc << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7) ;  
        else
            crc = (crc << 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: It is not the STM32 engine.  He is using ARMv7/ARMv8 crc opcodes.